# JPQL : multiple join. How to do my namedquery?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

Here's a quick diagram of my database.

http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/2474/mpd.png

In this scheme, I created JPA entities (for all tables with a red square).

I would like to create a JPQL query to get all aircraft that have references, references defined by a reference type given by parameter.

I tried :
    `SELECT DISTINCT a FROM Aircraft a JOIN FETCH a.references r WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ref FROM Reference ref WHERE ref = r AND ref.referenceType.id = :id)`

But i have an error cause Eclipse doesnt like the alias in `JOIN FETCH a.references *r*` and the request doesnt work in JUnit test.

Here my entities without getter/setter :

**Aircraft**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_R_AIRCRAFT_AIR", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "AIR_NAME"))
public class Aircraft implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "AIR_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @TableGenerator(name="aircraftSeqStore", 
        table="T_S_APP_SEQ_STORE_AST", 
        pkColumnName="AST_SEQ_NAME",
        valueColumnName = "AST_SEQ_VALUE",
        pkColumnValue = "T_R_AIRCRAFT_AIR.AIR_ID", 
        allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, 
        generator="aircraftSeqStore")       
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "AIR_NAME", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "T_J_REF_AIR_RFA", 
               joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "RFA_AIR_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
               inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "RFA_REF_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private Set<Reference> references = new HashSet<Reference>(0);

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "T_J_MAN_AIR_MNA", 
               joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "MNA_AIR_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
               inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "MNA_MAN_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) })  
    private Set<Manual> manuals = new HashSet<Manual>(0);

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
               mappedBy = "aircraft",
               cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE })
    private Set<UserConfig> userConfigs = new HashSet<UserConfig>(0);
}
```

** Reference **

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_E_REFERENCE_REF", 
       uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "REF_IDENTIFIER"))
public class Reference implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "REF_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @TableGenerator(name="referenceSeqStore", 
        table="T_S_APP_SEQ_STORE_AST", 
        pkColumnName="AST_SEQ_NAME",
        valueColumnName = "AST_SEQ_VALUE",
        pkColumnValue = "T_E_REFERENCE_REF.REF_ID", 
        allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="referenceSeqStore")                   
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "REF_IDENTIFIER", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)  
    private String identifier;

    @Column(name = "REF_LINK")  
    private String link;

    @Column(name = "REF_OBSERVATIONS", length = 4000)
    private String observations;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "REF_RFT_ID", nullable = false)  
    private ReferenceType referenceType;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "REF_MAN_ID")    
    private Manual manual;  

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
               mappedBy = "reference",
               cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE })
    private Set<Translation> translations = new HashSet<Translation>(0);

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "T_J_REF_AIR_RFA", 
               joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "RFA_REF_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
               inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "RFA_AIR_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private Set<Aircraft> aircrafts = new HashSet<Aircraft>(0);
}
```

** ReferenceType **

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_R_REFERENCE_TYPE_RFT", 
       uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "RFT_TYPE"))
public class ReferenceType implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "RFT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @TableGenerator(name="referenceTypeSeqStore", 
        table="T_S_APP_SEQ_STORE_AST", 
        pkColumnName="AST_SEQ_NAME",
        valueColumnName = "AST_SEQ_VALUE",
        pkColumnValue = "T_R_REFERENCE_TYPE_RFT.RFT_ID", 
        allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="referenceTypeSeqStore")                   
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "RFT_TYPE", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)    
    private String type;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
               mappedBy = "referenceType", 
               cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE })    
    private Set<Reference> references = new HashSet<Reference>(0);

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
               mappedBy = "referenceType",
               cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE })    
    private Set<UserConfig> userConfigs = new HashSet<UserConfig>(0);
}
```

PS: I forgot to say that a table had been added between Aircraft and Reference. This is the Manual table. But i dont think there is an impact.

PS2: JPA implementation is made by Hibernate.

Any idea how to make the multiple join ?
Thank you !

Comment: How to join an entity which is already a join from one ? i.e how to join A with B with C ? it seems easy to join A with B, and A with C but for others big join i dont succeed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can execute your query much easier as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a FROM Aircraft a JOIN FETCH a.references r 
LEFT JOIN FETCH a.manuals 
WHERE r.referenceType.id = :id
```

I've added `join fetch a.manuals` since otherwise I got `LazyInitializationException`. Added `LEFT` to prevent the absence of manuals to influence on the output.

Comment: Finally, i have a pb with my JUnit test. Too many lazy loading, so many collections are loaded and i have a outofmemory. I have difficulty with JPQL. So i dunno if my JPQL is working or not. Put an alias after a join fetch seems not be accepted by JPA Validator. For moment your answer does not allow me to understand how it works. Is this JPQL could be correct : `SELECT DISTINCT a FROM Aircraft a JOIN FETCH a.references JOIN FETCH a.references.referenceType WHERE a.references.referenceType.id = :id` ? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: No, this query won't work since this path `a.references.referenceType` isn't valid. Think yourself: you reference `referenceType` property of `references` collection which the latter obviously doesn't have.

Comment: I understand that using join fetch was done to "load" the collections configured for the lazy loading?
So is it possible to create a nested query? in SQL, we probably did it first by a query to select all references for a ReferenceType Id, then some joints to get the aircrafts (via the join table).

Comment: In JPQL you should forget about join tables since here you work with @Entities, @ElementCollections, @Embeddabbles and so on. In JPQL you will need joins only when you want to get access to entity through @ManyToMany or @OneToMany association as in the current case. Otherwise, if there was @OneToOne or @ManyToOne association of Aircraft with Reference then you could formulate your query as follows:
`SELECT DISTINCT a FROM Aircraft a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.manuals 
WHERE a.reference.referenceType.id = :id`

Comment: Ok. Thank you for these explanations. So, if I sum up, joins are necessary for all `@ManyToMany` & `@OneToMany` associations, but not for `@ManyToOne` & `@OneToOne`....except if there is a lazy loading where we still need to do a join fetch to "load" our entity. That is exact ?

Comment: `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToOne` are eager-loaded by default so unless you specify them as `FetchType.EAGER` you won't need even JOIN FETCH for them. Also, FYI, `@ManyToMany` or `@OneToMany` are lazy-loaded by default.

Comment: Hhhmmm...so i have to change my entities perhaps. After an automatic generation with HibernateTools to create JPA entities, i have some associations like that : `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`.

Comment: I don't understand. Your JPQL seems not to be good. When i run on server, there is an error : Errors in named queries Aircraft.refType.

Comment: 1. Alias seems not be tolarated in a join fetch query. 2. JPQL seems to precognize INNER JOIN FETCH. I didn't totaly resolved the pb. I'm still working on it...

Comment: On my end the query works as it should be, so the issue isn't with query. You can check my implementation of your case here:
https://github.com/bondarenko/so_11950279

Comment: My application crashed on init when there is a verification of named query in each entity. It seemes you used Spring.data. For my part, when i create a named query based on javax.persistence.namedquery in the entity i have some errors detected by Dali, and error in runtime.

Comment: Anyway, i won't multiplicate subjets on JPQL but i still have a question : how to manage `@ManyToMany` associations so ? If we have in the manual table some `@ManyToMany` with aircrafts, how to create a JPQL where we can filter with aircraft ID ? It's very strange to pass from SQL to JPQL :( For my case, i know i can create a JPQL like that `SELECT m FROM Manual INNER JOIN FETCH m.aircrafts` but it's impossible to use aircrafts in where clause with fetch condition. Should we force eager mode for this association, delete fetch, add an alias et add the criteria in where clause ?

Comment: OMG, sorry for the last question. I just realized even if i have some collections loaded in lazy mode, i can realize a request juste with inner join without fetching but using it into the where clause !!! But for alias in join fetch, it seems realy forbidden in JPQL, not HQL.